# How to change value of Submit form button only if all required fields of the form are filled in (JS)

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I want to change the value of submit form button to "Loading..." with JAVA SCRIPT only if all the required fields in the form are filled in. Please help. Thank you!!!

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <input id="my-file" name="my-file" type="file" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="email" value="" name="my_email" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="visible_submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var mySubmit = document.getElementById("visible_submit");
mySubmit.onclick = function addLoading() { document.getElementById("visible_submit").setAttribute("value", "Loading...");};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of listening for the `click` event on the submit button, listen for the `submit` event on the form.

Use `checkValidity()` to check whether the user has filled all the required fields, and `Event.preventDefault()` to prevent form submission:

```js
var mySubmit = document.getElementById("visible_submit");
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  if (form.checkValidity()) {
    document.getElementById("visible_submit").value = "Loading...";
  }
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input id="my-file" name="my-file" type="file" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="email" value="" name="my_email" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="visible_submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It worked! thank you! the only problem is that my form had to redirect user after they hit Submit (<form action="https://formspree.io/f/mwkayjea"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">) But the redirection does not work now... I am wondering if you know the reason. Thanks

Comment: oh. I  just removed "e.preventDefault();" and the form started to redirect. Thank you again! cheers